# Using "connect" from Redux with react-css-modules

Tags: react-redux, react-css-modules

So far i've been using Redux "connect" to connect components with state, I export my components the following way:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ComponentTitle);
```

I now want to use react-css-modules, but i'll have to do it using the following export in each component:

```
export default CSSModules(ComponentTitle, styles);
```

How can I export the component to have both functionalities?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your react component with css functionality before connect to redux.

```
const ComponentWithCSS = CSSModules(ComponentTitle, styles);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ComponentWithCSS);
```